# selenium 2.45 with mac 10.11 and safari 9 not able to run

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safaridriver, safari9

I am not able to run selenium with mac 10.11 and safari 9.
Error is : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: SafariDriver requires Safari 10 running on OSX El Capitan or greater.

Configuration I used are :
Selenium : 2.45.0; 2.48.0
Safari browser version : 9.1.3
Mac OS 10.11.6 OS X El Capitan
Java JDK : 1.8

Safari extension I used is from 2.45 or 2.48 selenium from link http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and have installed safari extension in safari. I am using maven to download selenium.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Did it used to work? Did you try to diagnose this at all? There is not enough information present to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well the exception says
`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: SafariDriver requires Safari 10 running on OSX El Capitan or greater.`

And you said you are using:

> Safari browser version : 9.1.3

I'd say you have to update your browser.

Comment: Thanks for simple answer though not what I am looking for .. I have to run in Safari 9 and not Safari 10.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing issues in initiating safari browser on mac machine, and below solution helped me. I am using 
Java 8,
Selenium Webdriver,
TestNG,
Page Object Model, 
Page Factory in my GUI automation framework.

```
if (browserType.equals("safari")) {
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver", workingDir +
            // "//driver//SafariDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver",
                    "/driver/SafariDriver.safariextz");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities
                    .safari();
            SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
            safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
            safariOptions.getUseCleanSession();
            safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY,
                    safariOptions);

            // deleteCookies();
            driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new SafariDriver());

            ThreadDriver.set(driver);
            // driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 850));
            getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        }
```